How to get selected text when triple clicks?
When I triple click the last word in comment of issue in github, web will select the whole content of this comment rather than the current line in other websites. This is the first point I have seen.
I want to get the selected text in javascript, but function window.getSelection().toString() only catch the content in current line, I don't know how to get the whole content in comment.
When I print window.getSelection() on console, I found window.getSelection() -> anchorNode -> innerText is what I want, but if I only get undefine as the return of window.getSelection().anchorNode.innerText in my code, meanwhile, the return of window.getSelection().anchorNode is also different with anchorNode content in the log of window.getSelection() (return of window.getSelection().anchorNode is a string and anchorNode content in the log of window.getSelection() is a json which contains lots of contents).
I want to know how I can get the expected content(whole comment) in javascript?
Pictures of log as below:
Log of window.getSelection()
Log of window.getSelection().anchorNode, this is just a string of current selected line content.

GitHub makes use of the CSS rule user-select: contain. Since this is not yet supported by browsers in the standard, they load a polyfill which simulates this effect on elements with class="user-select-contain".


<div style="user-select: contain" class="user-select-contain">
  <p>Select this paragraph</p>
  <p>together with this paragraph.</p>
</div>



